# How do i turn 2 prompt answers into 1 result for a concatenation

Tags: javascript

I need to create javascript that asks what the temperature is like then kick out a string based on the temperature then ask what type of event they're going to and kick out a string based on their answer then put both of those answers into 1 result and put it into my concatenation

```
let temp = "What is the temperature today?";
let event = "What type of event are you going to?";
let result2 = {
    casual: "something comfy",
    semiformal: "a polo",
    formal: "a suit",
}

let tempFahr = prompt(temp);
let eventType = prompt(event);
let result1 = "";
let result = result1 + result2;

console.log(tempFahr);
console.log(eventType);

if (eventType == result2.casual) {
    let result2 = "something comfy";
} else if (eventType == result2.semiformal) {
    let result2 = "a polo";
} else if (eventType == result2.formal) {
    let result2 = "a suit";
}

if(tempFahr <= 54) {
    console.log("a coat")
} else if(tempFahr >=55 && 70) {
    console.log("a jacket")
} else if(tempFahr > 70) {
    console.log("no jacket")
}

console.log(`since it is ${tempFahr} degrees and you are going to a ${eventType} event, you should wear ${result}`);

----This is what's expected----
“Since it is 33 degrees and you are going to a formal event, you should wear a suit
and coat.

----This is the actual output----
66            script.js:15
casual        script.js:36 
a jacket      script.js:45 
since it is 66 degrees and you are going to a casual event, you should wear [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have confused a couple of concepts.  First, for handling the event type, your first "result2" definition is essentially a table of resulting clothing.  So the block

```
if (eventType == result2.casual) {
    let result2 = "something comfy";
} else if (eventType == result2.semiformal) {
    let result2 = "a polo";
} else if (eventType == result2.formal) {
    let result2 = "a suit";
}
```

can be shortened to

```
let clothing = result2[eventType];
```

As it is now, it is comparing the event type to the clothing types.  BTW, you'd probably want a bit of error handling on that as well.

Secondly, for the temperature block, you are logging the outcome, but not saving it in a variable.  So

```
if(tempFahr <= 54) {
    console.log("a coat")
} else if(tempFahr >=55 && 70) {
    console.log("a jacket")
} else if(tempFahr > 70) {
    console.log("no jacket")
}
```

should be something like

```
if(tempFahr <= 54) {
    jacket = "a coat";
} else if(tempFahr >=55 && tempFahr <= 70) {
    jacket = "a jacket";
} else if(tempFahr > 70) {
    jacket = "no jacket";
}
```

And then your final output statement will need to be changed to match the new variable names I've chosen.  I changed them because your existing naming was a bit confused.

Comment: thank you very much! but it seems the tempFahr lines aren't working correctly any idea why?

Comment: I hadn't fixed one problem in the middle conditional for the temperatures.  I corrected it now.  Hope it works.